# Log Stored procedure parameters in new relic trace

Tags: c#, asp.net, newrelic

We have new relic logging inplace, and I can see our stored procedure calls, but I would really like to incorporate the parameter values within the trace details.

Is there an easy way to do this? (the app is an asp.net web app)

Comment: I would suggest putting more effort into your question for example.. `Show a code sample of what you are working with and or have tried` this is a very poor question in my opinion

Comment: I do not have a coding example. I am asking the question to see if adding parameter values to the new relic trace is even possible. I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Errors and transactions traces can include parameters, yes. You will need to use the .NET API. Instructions for implementing the API can be found here:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/net-agent-api

One of the following two methods is used for this:

AddCustomParameter(System.String,System.IConvertible) - For numerical values
AddCustomParameter(System.String,System.String) - For string values

Further details are included in the page by clicking the down-arrow to the right of each method.

Comment: Fantastic! I was sure there was some way I could do something like this. I was hoping there was just a configuration flag we could set, but, I believe I can implement this in our system